# Fetch query is sending on the server twice

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo

The result of the mutation should update the data without an unnecessary request to the server, I do not understand what needs to be corrected so that the data is not fetched twice, but taken from the cache.

```
  const [createEvent, { loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_GOOD_MUTATION, {
    variables: values,
    update(proxy, result) {
      // TODO: remove goods from cache
      const data = proxy.readQuery({
        query: FETCH_ITEMS_QUERY,
      });
      let newData = [...data.events];
      newData = [result.data.events, ...newData];
      proxy.writeQuery({
        query: FETCH_ITEMS_QUERY,
        data: {
          ...data,
          events: {
            newData,
          },
        },
      });
    },
    // refetchQueries: [
    //   {
    //     query: FETCH_ITEMS_QUERY,
    //   },
    // ],
    onError(err) {
      setErrors(err.message);
    },
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia1us.png)

Mutation to create a new good:

```
CREATE_GOOD_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation createEvent(
    $title: String!
    $description: String!
    $price: String!
    $autor: String!
    $pageNumber: String!
    $publishYear: String!
  ) {
    createEvent(
      eventInput: {
        title: $title
        description: $description
        price: $price
        autor: $autor
        pageNumber: $pageNumber
        publishYear: $publishYear
      }
    ) {
      title
      description
      price
    }
  }
`;
```

Query to display all products:

```
FETCH_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query events {
    events {
      id
      title
      description
      price
    }
  }
`;
```

I need to fetch it once, when I try to create a new good by mutation and display all products from the cache, without an additional request.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `proxy.modify` instead of `proxy.readQuery`/`proxy.writeQuery`.

[Using cache.modify](http://using-cachemodify)

[Making cache updates with mutation.update function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates)

Try to change your mutation `update` function to something like this:

```js
update(proxy, result) {
  proxy.modify({
    fields: {
      events(existingEvents = []) {
        return [...existingEvents, result.data.createEvent];
      }
    }
  })
},
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but nothing changed. Still fetched twice.

Comment: Are you sure that the `proxy.modify` call is making that duplicit refetch?

Comment: I'm sure, the first request causes a mutation, and the second one displays all products as in the picture above. I tried to leave only this code: return [...existingEvents]; instead return [...existingEvents, result.data.createEvent]; and mutation triggered without updating products. 
I'm stuck.